# How can I construct a Grafana template Graphite query that only returns data with a value

Tags: grafana

I've got a dashboard with a template variable for our VM instances based on their hostname and the dashboard repeats a row of panels of collectd graphs (CPU, memory, etc) based on the items in that variable.

However when we rotate out VMs the Graphite data hangs around for a while, but the data is empty, so i don't want to show them in the dropdown.

The current query is

`platform.collectd.*`

I tried something like this to filter out the ones with no current data, but it returns nothing in the list:

`aliasByNode(maximumAbove(platform.collectd.*.cpu-0.percent-idle.value,0),2)`

It seems it only works with a wildcard at the end.

Is there any way to get around this?